# Graph Theory: Path from one point to another(directed graph)

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose G is a directed graph and v,v' are two of its vertices.

You are told that $A^{4}_{v,v}$ , $A^{7}_{v,v'}$ , $A^{5}_{v',v'}$ are nonzero. For which values of x does this knowledge guarantee the existence of paths from v to v' of length x?

My try:

From what I have understood it should be 7 right? because it clearly tells us that there exist a length of path 7 from v to v'

Comment: " For which values of  does this knowledge " Of what ?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the 'x' somehow

Comment: And what´s the meaning of $A_{v,v}^4$  ?

Comment: that there is a path of length 4 from vertex v to itself

Comment: why it is written that $A_{v,v}^4$ is nonzero if it has obviously the length 4  ?

Comment: It's a notation

Comment: But this information would be redundant. Beside this. The minimum length of the path from v to v' is 7. If this is the question then you´re right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the path you found, of length $7$.  There's another path $v \xrightarrow{4} v \xrightarrow{7} v'$ of length $11$ (where the overset integers indicate the length of that path component).  There's another path $v \xrightarrow{7} v' \xrightarrow{5} v'$ of length $12$.

You *have* found the shortest path (using only the three adjacency facts that you are given), but there are many additional paths that cycle around at the ends, growing larger and larger.  All these paths taken together have lengths $$ \{7 + 4 m + 5 n : m,n \in \Bbb{Z}, m \geq 0, n \geq 0 \}  \text{.}$$

Comment: Got it. That we have to consider all the three cases. Thank you